# how can I add the user input to the ul without repeating li values?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make web page with by HTML and Javascript, which has ages as a section and names. it will look like 
[image: a]
 the web page allow the user to enter new person and display it.
**"If the age entered already exist in the page the name will be added under it, IF not it will create new age section.".** My question is how can I add the user input to the list without repeating age values?
For example, if user entered name: Abbey ,age: 18. And 18 is already in the list the page will display the name under 18 without creating another "18" section

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <ul>
        <li>30</li>
        <ul>
            <li>Joe</li>
            <li>Adam</li>
        </ul>
        <li>50</li>
            <ul>
               <li>Scot</li>
            </ul>
    </ul>
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Add New</button>   
    <script>
    function myFunction(){
        var name = prompt("Please enter first name");
        var age = prompt("Please enter second name");
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either add a class based on the age value, then use that class to select the correct li or select the li by text. With jquery the selector would be $('li:contains(18)')

Comment: I added the code, could just make it with my code because i'm not familiar with Jquery. thanks @gabsoft